# Where to place a sqlite file in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing directly on the mobile device, and I have some questions you hopefully could help me clarify about development using a database:

- My app is meant to use a SQLite database (readonly mode), so I'd like
  to know where I should place the .sqlite file created on the pc, in
  order for the app to read or even directly.
- Later, the app is supposed to download the db file from a
  centralized server. So, the idea is to keep putting that file in the
  same location, one the app will surely know and could check if it
  exists just before trying to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to package your SQLite database as a resource (e.g., res/raw) or asset with your application. However, you won't be able to use the packaged SQLite database directly. You will need to copy it to where Android expects your app's database files to be located and then use it from there. The best way to do this is to use [`Context.getDatabasePath(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) (passing the name of the database file) to determine the file path. That's also where you should place a database file that your app downloads at run time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's now clear for me how it must be done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the database file into your assets folder, then write it to memory to access in the app using the following code:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String TAG = "DataBaseHelper";

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + Constants.package_name + "/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "YourDatabaseName.db";

public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 

private final Context myContext;

    

 
/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    
}   

  /**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getWritableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    
    

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
 
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your DataBaseHelper class, you should use `myContext.getDatabasePath("YourDatabaseName")` instead of hard-coding `DB_PATH`.

Comment: i've had code similar to this in a production app for a while and while it seems to work most of the time, I have a suspicion that here and there the database gets slightly corrupted or altered during the copy. I've notice missing columns and corrupt table indices.

Comment: Many thanks for the code, i'll try making some modifications.

Comment: (SOLVED)
I finally got it to work placing the file in assets and modifying this code with Ted's advice of using `getDatabasePath()`.
If anyone needs: [CODE HERE](http://pastebin.com/6LnmHWsj)

Answer (score 1):

I put my initial database in 'assets' directory and then copy it on user-accessable path - like external memory (sdcard and so on). I hadn't any troubles using this way :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest if you want to insert data as well rather just fetching values, you can make database inside the application

which will always have the path:

```
/data/data/your_project_name/databases/yourdatabase_name.db
```

[http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/](https://web.archive.org/web/20111013163043/http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial#title)

Comment: For the path, one should use `your_project_package` (as declared in the manifest), not `your_project_name`. In any event, the best way to determine the path is to use `context.getDatabasePath("yourdatabase_name")`.